# how to create a checkbox group in zend framework 2

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, zend-form, zend-framework2

i am trying to create a checkbox group, something like:

```
Checkbox Label
|_| Checkbox1
|_| Checkbox2
...
```

i found this code that renders one checkbox only

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'checkbox',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'A checkbox ',
            'checked_value' => 'good',
            'unchecked_value' => 'bad',

        )
    ));
```

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.elements.html#multicheckbox-element

Answer (score 2):

There is article with full example of multicheckbox processing (including storing/reading in DB):

[Zend Framework 2 : Extending Zend\Form to add Select, Multicheckbox, Email,Date, Textarea, and Radio element](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/zend-framework-2-extending-zendform-to-add-select-multicheckbox-emaildate-textarea-and-radio-element/)